# Making a phone call from within an app

Tags: iphone, call, voice

Is there any way to make a call from within an app without quitting the app? If yes please help. If not, what should I do to save the state of the app before quitting the app and resuming from that state on restart?
Thanks for any reply..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app initiates a call, the OS quits your app, giving you a little time in the background to save the app's state, and launches the phone app.

It's up to you to save all your settings and the state of the app such as what view you are in to a plist.  Upon launch, go through and initialize your settings and state with that plist.

There is no easy way to do this.  Only you know what information needs to be saved and reinstated in order to restore your app to the state that it was in before being quit.